# KendoUI Scheduler Event Color

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have the following code in my `resources: []` array, which sets the color of an event.  In my case, the actual event tile doesnt change colors, but in the `color` dropdown of the event, I see the three intended options, tho they have no effect.

```
                {
                    field: 'color',
                    dataColorField: 'color',
                    dataValueField: 'color',
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: 'blue', color: 'blue' },
                        { text: 'red', color: 'red' },
                        { text: 'green', color: 'green' }
                    ]
                }
```

[image: As you can see, there are options to change the edited tile to blue, green, or red, but none of them have any effect.]

Answer (score 0):

In your dataSource field of resources "value" field is missing. So a default colour is shown . If you add the value property in dataSource of resources array you will see different resource's event in different colours.

Comment: Example:
dataSource: [
                {
                    taskId: 1,
                    title: "ABC", 
                    start: "2017/1/12 11:00",
                    end: "2017/1/12 12:00",
                },
            ],
            resources: [{
                field: "taskId",
                dataSource: [{ color: "green", text: " ", value: 1 }]
            }],